# How to run symfony via docker-composer

Tags: symfony, ubuntu, nginx, docker

I git cloned this repository: [docker-symfony](https://github.com/eko/docker-symfony) and followed the installation instructions.

When I visited `symfony.dev:81`, I saw kibana 4.

My problem is, I don't understand where I should put the Symfony project.

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions mention:

> **put your Symfony application into `symfony` folder** and do not forget to add `symfony.dev` in your `/etc/hosts` file.
>
> Then, run:

```
$ docker-compose up
```

> You are done, **you can visite your Symfony application on the following URL: http://symfony.dev** (and access Kibana on http://symfony.dev:81)

That "`symfony` folder" comes from [`docker-compose.yml#L4`](https://github.com/eko/docker-symfony/blob/a3c522c2a83b556eaf488afd8e049387813d831e/docker-compose.yml#L4)

```
volumes:
    - ./symfony:/var/www/symfony
```

It means you should create a `symfony` folder in your `docker-symfony` cloned repo, which will be mounted as `/var/www/symfony` in the application container.

```
docker-symfony
  code
  elk/logstash
  nginx
  php-fpm
  .gitignore
  .travis.yml
  README.md
  symfony   <====== Add your folder there
```

That folder can be a symbolic link to wherever you have your `symfony` project.